# Is it possible to retrieve the controller of a directive compiled inside another directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm stuck on structuring components inside a large AngularJS application I've been maintaining and I'd really love some guidance since I'm at my wits end. Please bear with me!

**Context:**

I've got some directives that I'd like to have communicating with each other. As such, I thought it was appropriate to define a controller in each directive to expose an API for other directives to make use of. Now, I'm well aware of the `require` property in directives and how one can pull in the controllers of parent directives to use. Unfortunately, in my current circumstances, I have directives that don't necessary fit the use of requiring controllers.

Instead of using `require`, the code base I'm faced with has mostly chosen to add directives directly to the DOM and then to compile them afterwards. I suppose this was to allow for flexibility on customising how directives depend on each other.

I've included a snippet from the `link` function out of the demonstration Plunker further below that I created to help visualise the problem I'm facing. Note how directives are being attached to the DOM and then being compiled. I tried as best as I could to create a simplified version of the code I'm actually working on because I can't post it.

```
link: function(scope, elem) {
  scope.data = '...';
  var d2Elem = elem.find('li').eq(0);
  d2Elem.attr('d2', '');
  var input = angular.element('<input type="text" ng-model="data">');
  elem.find('li').eq(-1).append(input);
  $compile(d2Elem)(scope);
  $compile(input)(scope);
  // Able to get d1 directive controller
  console.log(elem.controller('d1'));
  // Not able to get compiled d2 directive controller
  console.log(d2Elem.controller('d2'));
  // Able to get compiled ng-model directive controller
  console.log(input.controller('ngModel'));
}
```

**Question:**

Could somebody please explain why I'm seeing the behaviour I commented on in my Plunker? Why is it that when I compile a directive I've defined (i.e. `d2`), I cannot access it's corresponding controller even though it exists in the directive definition?

Coincidentally, I found that after compiling the built-in `ng-model` directive, I can in fact get its controller.

*An extra point I'm pondering:* Is the process I've described the least painful way to go about managing directives that communicate with each other? Noting that these directives don't necessary have strict parent-child relationships.

[<kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/FexNvJjXlF5rWRvoSSjO?p=preview)

Would very much appreciate some thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

It is taking time until d2.html is being loaded asynchronously by Ajax, until it's loaded completely you cannot access it's controller, see attached screenshot, after ajax call it's able to access controller of d2.

[image]

I tried by replacing

```
console.log(d2Elem.controller('d2'))}
```

with

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log(d2Elem.controller('d2'))},1000);
```

And it worked for me, may be this will give you some hint or may be putting delay will resolve your issue, I know this is not good practice!!

Comment: Good observation, thank you. Though I wonder why there's a delay until the controller is made available. Maybe it has something to do with the `$compile` call not immediately executing a `$digest` after it's done.